# MonadError instance for monad-coroutine Coroutine for any suspension Functor

Tags: haskell, coroutine, monad-transformers

Is it possible to write a `MonadError` instance for a `monad-coroutine` `Coroutine` with an arbitrary suspension `Functor`.

i.e.

```
instance (MonadError e m, Functor s) => MonadError (Coroutine s m) where
    throwError = lift . throwError
    catchError c h = lift $ catchError (_ c) (_ . h)
```

What can go in the holes?  They need to convert a `Coroutine s m r` to an `m r` but I don't see how that's possible for arbitrary `s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. `Coroutine` is essentially the same as [`FreeT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1.7/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Free.html#t:FreeT), and the latter has a `MonadError` instance.

Note that you started off wrong; you can't begin with `lift`. The problem shows up earlier than you think.

```
    catchError :: Coroutine f m a -> (e -> Coroutine f m a) -> Coroutine f m a
    catchError c f = lift _

==>

_ :: m a
```

Even if you don't have to deal with catching errors, there's no way you can fill that hole!

`lift` really isn't up to the task of lifting `catch`-like functions in general.

Comment: I'm ditching `Coroutine` and switching to `FreeT`.

Answer (score 2):

This type-checks. I'm not sure whether it's lawful, though.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Bifunctor
import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.Coroutine

instance (MonadError e m, Functor s) => MonadError e (Coroutine s m) where
    throwError = lift . throwError
    Coroutine c `catchError` h = Coroutine $ fmap (first (fmap (`catchError` h))) c `catchError` (resume . h)
```

In English, here's how this works: First, try running a single step of `c`. Three cases are possible:

- If that throws an error, then we handle the error with `h` and return whatever it does.
- If that succeeds and returns a final value, then we return that same final value.
- If that succeeds and returns a suspension, then we didn't get an error yet, but still might later, so we `` fmap (`catchError` h) `` over the suspension functor and return that, recursing so that we have a chance to catch it later.

EDIT: I wrote this before I saw dfeuer's answer or knew about `FreeT`'s instance, but that instance is eerily similar to this one. That makes me think this one is lawful.

Comment: I have never checked that for lawfulness. The `Alternative` instance for `FreeT` is rather sketchy, as I recall (whereas the one for `Stream` in `streaming` is more principled), but *most* of the instances are reasonable.

Comment: Ha ha ha ha. I just went to see if I could figure out whether the instance is lawful, and determined that it is vacuously so—the class has no laws whatsoever.

Comment: I guess it would probably be impossible to write useful laws, since the interface doesn't admit concepts like "doesn't throw an error".